# Cannot upgrade from 23.04 to 23.10 due to kept back nvidia packages

Tags: nvidia, package-management, upgrade, 23.10

The GUI just finishes when I press the "Upgrade..." button. Very impolitely. I then tried the command line and got:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
(...)
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic
  linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-39-generic
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 4 not to upgrade.
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

How to proceed? May I force the distribution upgrade? Or can I force the package update? Or can I tell the machine to ignore the kept back packages? And why am I the only one who has this problem?

Addendum: The reinstall method does **not** work:

```
$ sudo apt reinstall linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-39-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-535 (>= 535.154.05) but 535.146.02-0ubuntu0.23.04.1 is to be installed
 linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-535 (>= 535.154.05) but 535.146.02-0ubuntu0.23.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Addendum II: This one (from the linked issue) might have worked, at least I am now starting the upgrade:

```
sudo apt install --only-upgrade linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-39-generic
```

This **removed** the packages linux-modules-nvidia-530-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic
linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04. Afterwards apt dist-upgrade upgraded linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic.

Finally I am rather confused about that mechanism, but am going to start the upgrade process now, via *do-release-upgrade*.

Comment: You have this problem because you installed packages from a non Ubuntu source. To fix the problem remove all the packages and the non Ubuntu source

Comment: You can force those upgrades by running `sudo apt reinstall linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-39-generic linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-39-generic`

Comment: I would really NOT remove the graphics drivers and continue using the system with command line. I will later try the other hint.

Comment: "kept back" is less of a problem and more like a regular situation. It just means you need to run `sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: Thanks for the hints so far! I will report the results as soon as I find time to retry the upgrade.

Comment: The upgrade first seemed to have completed well, but then the system started with a black screen -- due to a kernel module that was rejected (unavailable key).  Solved with: Boot do maintenance mode, then resume, wait one (!) minute of flashing cursor, then the GUI starts, probably without graphics driver and without animations, then run "sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia:535" and removing the "-545" modules.